# Import custom modules on IPython.parallel engines with sync_imports()

Tags: python, ipython, ipython-parallel

I've been playing around with IPython.parallel and I wanted to use some custom modules of my own, but haven't been able to do it as explained on [the cookbook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html) using `dview.sync_imports()`. The only thing that has worked for me was something like

```py
def my_parallel_func(args):
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/path/to/my/module')
    import my_module
    #and all the rest
```

and then in the main just to

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
     #set up dview...
     dview.map( my_parallel_func, my_args )
```

The correct way to do this would in my opinion be something like

```py
 with dview.sync_imports():
     import sys
     sys.path.append('/path/to/my/module')
     import my_module
```

but this throws an error saying there is no module named `my_module`.

So, what is the right way of doing it using `dview.sync_imports()`??

Comment: right, but sys.path does. Corrected it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the `PYTHONPATH` just in the local process running the Client, and not in the remote processes running in the `ipcluster`.

You can observe this behaviour if you run the next piece of code:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client

rc = Client()
dview = rc[:]

with dview.sync_imports():
    import sys
    sys.path[:] = ['something']
   
def parallel(x):
    import sys
    return sys.path

print 'Local: ', sys.path
print 'Remote: ', dview.map_sync(parallel, range(1))
```

Basically all the modules that you want to use with `sync_imports` must already be in the `PYTHONPATH`.

If it's not in the `PYTHONPATH` then you must add it to the path in the function that you execute remotely, and then import the module in the function.

Comment: Ok, so I did that, but for some reason the remote engines are not getting the PYTHONPATH right. What environment do the remote engines get their PYTHONPATH from? The one I ran the script from? The default shell for the system? Python config files? I ran your exact script, PYTHONPATH is correctly configured, the local import works, the remote import doesn't.

Comment: @AlexS How do you start the remote engines? `ipcluster start -n 4`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I managed to get around the problem by modifying the engine startup script top import sys and modifying sys.path directly. Then the imports work normally..

Comment: @AlexS You should just modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. I think it would be easier... If you're on posix system just run it as: `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/module ipcluster start -n 4`

Comment: I'm on a debian box, using zshell, both bash and Zsh show the correct PYTHONPATH if i run `echo $(PYTHONPATH)`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Right, if i run the ipcluster command that way it should work.

Comment: Your module is in python path? Weird :-#

Comment: just as a hint: the working directory from which you run `ipcluster start -n 4` is in the `PYTHONPATH`. If all required custom modules are in the same directory, running `ipcluster` from this directory is a possible way to go.